# Is storing a reference to a parent possible with Rust?

Tags: rust

I have the following struct:

```rust
pub struct Scope<'parent> {
    entries: HashMap<String, Type>,
    parent: Option<&'parent mut Self>,
}

impl<'parent> Scope<'parent> {
    pub fn with_parent(parent: &'parent mut Self) -> Self {
        Scope {
            entries: HashMap::new(),
            parent: Some(parent),
        }
    }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////

fn analyze_expression<'input>(
    errors: &mut Vec<CodeError>,
    wrapping_scope: &mut Scope,
    expression: Loc<Expression<'input>>,
) -> Result<AnnotatedExpression<'input>, AnalyzingError> {
    //
}
```

When trying to construct it, I get this error:

```
error[E0623]: lifetime mismatch
  --> garlicsem/src/lib.rs:74:44
   |
66 |     wrapping_scope: &mut Scope,
   |                     ----------
   |                     |
   |                     these two types are declared with different lifetimes...
...
74 |             let scope = Scope::with_parent(wrapping_scope);
   |                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ...but data from `wrapping_scope` flows into `wrapping_scope` here
```

Is this kind of construction possible? If not, what is the best way to implement something like this? Should I be using `Rc`?

When I add explicit lifetimes like @nullptr suggested, I get the following error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for borrow expression due to conflicting requirements
  --> garlicsem/src/lib.rs:78:56
   |
78 |                     .map(|e| analyze_statement(errors, &mut scope, e))
   |                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime `'_` as defined on the body at 78:26...
  --> garlicsem/src/lib.rs:78:26
   |
78 |                     .map(|e| analyze_statement(errors, &mut scope, e))
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: ...so that closure can access `scope`
  --> garlicsem/src/lib.rs:78:56
   |
78 |                     .map(|e| analyze_statement(errors, &mut scope, e))
   |                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime `'a` as defined on the function body at 64:31...
  --> garlicsem/src/lib.rs:64:31
   |
64 | fn analyze_expression<'input, 'a>(
   |                               ^^
note: ...so that the expression is assignable
  --> garlicsem/src/lib.rs:74:44
   |
74 |             let scope = Scope::with_parent(wrapping_scope);
   |                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: expected `&mut scope::Scope<'_>`
              found `&mut scope::Scope<'a>`
```

I am pretty sure that this kind of data structure just isn't possible in safe rust without using `Rc` or unsafe. Therefore I am wondering what the best way to implement this would be.

Comment: Can you post the `Scope::with_parent` function and also the initialization of `wrapping_scope`? My guess is that `wrapping_scope` on line 66 needs to have an explicit lifetime 'a.

Comment: @nullptr i edited my question. also, I had tried using explicit lifetimes, but since `Scope` takes a generic lifetime parameter, I get another lifetime error because the lifetimes don't match iirc.

Comment: does my solution fix your problem?

Comment: @nullptr i edited my question to show what happened when i tried adding an explicit lifetime

Comment: I've edited my answer with some example code that compiles @Ian Rehwinkel

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `struct Scope<'parent>`, `Option<&'parent mut Self>` is implicitly `Option<&'parent mut Scope<'parent>>`.

Thus, the `wrapping_scope: &mut Scope` parameter in `analyze_expression` needs to be `wrapping_scope: &'a mut Scope<'a>` with a `'a` lifetime added in the `analyze_expression<'input, 'a>` function.

To be explicit, this code compiles:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
struct Type;

pub struct Scope<'parent> {
    entries: HashMap<String, Type>,
    parent: Option<&'parent mut Self>,
}

impl<'parent> Scope<'parent> {
    pub fn with_parent(parent: &'parent mut Self) -> Self {
        Scope {
            entries: HashMap::new(),
            parent: Some(parent),
        }
    }
}

fn analyze_expression<'a>(wrapping_scope: &'a mut Scope<'a>) {
    let scope = Scope::with_parent(wrapping_scope);

    for (string, _typ) in scope.entries.iter() {
        println!("{:?}", string);
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution worked wonderfully after I changed it to be immutable (turns out i didn't need mutability).